# How do you do wildcard matches with XSLT?

Tags: xml, xslt

If I have a source file like this:

```
<animal name="fred_monkey" />
<animal name="jim_banana" />
<animal name="joe_monkey" />
```

Can I do an XPATH expression in my stylesheet which selects only the animals with the string '_monkey' in their name?

e.g.  wildcard match '*_monkey' ?

Comment: @iYasha I'm currently using 1.0,  but interested in learning the differences between the two.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

> Can I do an XPATH expression in my
> stylesheet which selects only the
> animals with the string '_monkey' in
> their name?
>
> e.g. wildcard match '*_monkey' ?

This wildcard means *a string ending with* "_monkey", not *a string containing* "_monkey".

**Use**:

```
//animal[ends-with(@name, '_monkey')]
```

The above uses the standard XPath 2.0 function **[`ends-with()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#func-ends-with)** and is thus available only in XSLT 2.0.

**In XSLT 1.0 use the following XPath 1.0 expression**:

```
//animal[substring(@name, string-length(@name) -6)='_monkey']
```

**It isn't recommended to use the `//` abbreviation as this may result in inefficient evaluation**. Use more specific chain of location tests whenever the structure of the XML document is known. For example, if the `animal` elements are all children of the top element of the XML document, then the following XPath (2.0 or 1.0, respectively) expressions might be more efficient:

```
/*/animal[ends-with(@name, '_monkey')]
```

and

```
/*/animal[substring(@name, string-length(@name) -6)='_monkey']
```

Depending on one's specific needs (e.g. you really meant "contains" and not "ends with"), the functions [**`contains()`**](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#function-contains), [**`starts-with()`**](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#function-starts-with) and [**`substring()`**](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#function-substring) may also be useful:

```
contains(someString, someTargetString)

starts-with(someString, someTargetString)

substring(someString, start-index, length) = someTargetString
```

**Finally, the `match` attribute of `<xsl:templates>` doesn't need to contain an absolute XPath expression** -- just a relative XPath expression that specifies enough context is recommended to be used.

Thus, the above used as match expressions will be something as:

```
<xsl:template match="animal[ends-with(@name, '_monkey')]">
```

and

```
<xsl:template match=
  "animal[substring(@name, string-length(@name) -6)='_monkey']">
```

Comment: How can I use this: `<xsl:for-each select="root/*[matches(name(.), 'grp')]">` in XSLT 1.0?

Comment: @Si8, You can't. The function `matches()` is available only in XPath 2.0 and thus can be used only in XSLT 2.0 and later versions. In XPath 1.0 one can use the `contains()` function and a small set of other string functions -- of course none of this accepts as parameter a RegEx.