# XSLT: How to count attributes, found with a stringmatch

Tags: algorithm, xslt, search, wildcard, xslt-2.0

I'm new to whole world writing code in xslt. I want the xsl code to look though every node/attributes in my xml file and search for '__(string)' and count 'result=success/failed'. I found a thread here on this site to help me out a little:
 [How do you do wildcard matches with XSLT?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3942394/how-do-you-do-wildcard-matches-with-xslt) 
I got my xsl code to find the string match. But then my problem is, I don't know how to write the code to count success and failed for the given stringmatch?  I wish for the output to look something like this:

```
     **(Casename)**  |  **(total success)** | **(total failed)**
     __(stringmatch1)|         2            |        0
     __(stringmatch2)|         0            |        2
```

Here is a sample of the xml file:

```
<report>
     <programtest user="testuser">
           <programtest software="test">
               <programtest testname="SW log">
               </programtest>
               <programtest testname="HW log">
               </programtest>
               <programtest testname="loop_program_test">
                  <programtest casename="test" iteration="1" result="success">
                     <programtest casename="__temp1" type="specifictestcase" result="success" >
                      </programtest>
                      <programtest casename="__temp2" type="specifictestcase" result="failed" >
                      </programtest>
                  </programtest>
                  <programtest casename="test" iteration="2" result="success">
                      <programtest casename="__temp1" type="specifictestcase" result="success" >
                      </programtest>
                      <programtest casename="__temp2" type="specifictestcase" result="failed" >
                      </programtest>
                  </programtest>
               </programtest>
           </programtest>
     </programtest>
</report>
```

Any help is appreciated! :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is a grouping issue. You need to group your results by the @casename attribute for each specific **programtest** element. In XSLT2.0, you would do this by means of the **xsl:for-each-group** element

```
<xsl:for-each-group select=".//programtest[@type='specifictestcase']" group-by="@casename">
```

Then, for each group, you would get the number of successes like so

```
<xsl:value-of select="count(current-group()[@result='succes'])"/>
```

(N.B. There may be a typo in your XML, as shouldn't it be 'success' and not 'succes'?)

Here is the full XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
   <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes"/>
   <xsl:template match="/report">
      <table>
         <tr>
            <th>**(Casename)**</th>
            <th>**(total success)**</th>
            <th>**(total failed)**</th>
         </tr>
         <xsl:for-each-group select=".//programtest[@type='specifictestcase']" group-by="@casename">
            <tr>
               <td>
                  <xsl:value-of select="current-grouping-key()"/>
               </td>
               <td>
                  <xsl:value-of select="count(current-group()[@result='succes'])"/>
               </td>
               <td>
                  <xsl:value-of select="count(current-group()[@result='failed'])"/>
               </td>
            </tr>
         </xsl:for-each-group>
      </table>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When applied to your sample XML, the following is output

```
<table>
   <tr>
      <th>**(Casename)**</th>
      <th>**(total success)**</th>
      <th>**(total failed)**</th>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>__temp1</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>0</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>__temp2</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>2</td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: This sounds like a good approche. And yeah, your right, its a typo. But trying this, gives me the error that my xml-editor doesn't  recognized the "for-each-group" extension.Im using VS2010 as xml-editor, and I made sure that im using XSLT v 2.0.

Comment: If you are using Visual Studio, then you will probably need an XSLT v1.0 solution as Microsoft's XML processor doesn't support 2.0.

Answer (score 1):

Well by doing

```
<xsl:variable name="matchedElements" select="//*[starts-with(@casename, '__')]"/>
<xsl:variable name="unmatchedElements" select="//*[not(starts-with(@casename, '__'))]"/>
```

you can find the elements and then you can output the numbers if needed e.g.

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
     <th>matched</th>
     <th>not matched</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td><xsl:value-of select="count($matchedElements)"/></td>
      <td><xsl:value-of select="count($unmatchedElements)"/></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Does that help?

I simply used `starts-with(@casename, '__')`, depending on your needs you can of course use other tests like `@casename = '__temp1'` or `matches(@casename, 'some regular expression pattern here')`.

Comment: Thanks, this is a good start. Though, my next problem will be, to tell the difference between '__(stringmatches)'.